# Address CSS general sibling selector and input:checked

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I've tried to address styles defined like this:

```
header input[type=checkbox] ~ div#example {max-height:0px;}
```

```
header input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div#example {max-height:100px;}
```

I would like to do something like

```
document.getElementById('example').style.maxHeight='10px';
```

but it should only change

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked
```

not the unchecked Version.

Maybe there is a way with nextElementSibling? Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the maxWidth when the input changes from unchecked to checked and vv.

```js
document.querySelector('header input[type=checkbox]').addEventListener('change', function(event) {

  document.getElementById('example').style.maxHeight = event.target.checked ? '10px' : '0px';
});
```

```css
header input[type=checkbox]~div#example {
  max-height: 0px;
}

header input[type=checkbox]:checked~div#example {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div id="example"></div>
</header>
```